# Java Microservice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have java rest controller application 
  4 - coarse grained services with multiple fine grained service. The application is running in multiple clusters. When operating in different JVM getting database exceptions since fine grained service are trying to insert value into DB at same time. I would like to get a solution to solve this parallel processing requests across multiple cluster. I am using spring boot, Hibernate and spring JPA configurations.

Thanks,
Sudharsan

Comment: I would prefer to have separate databases for each module.

Comment: can akka, react framework will work for this scenario only for 1 fine grained service